# created cases and closed cases in the last 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dynamics-crm

```
created date     created cases    closed cases   teams

6-03-2023         9                7              abc
7-03-2023         8                8              abc
8-03-2023         7                9              abc
9-03-2023         10               8              abc
10-03-2023        15              10              abc
```

I have case table need to show how many cases created in the last 7 days and closed cases in the last 7 days from perticular team,if there are 5 users under that team then it has to show all the users data which they have created and closed.

Please find the below code that I have written

```
select
COUNT (1) AS [CreatedCases],
 COUNT (CASE WHEN caseentity.statecode=1 THEN 1 END) AS [ClosedCases],
 al.Name as [Team Name]
 FROM filteredIncident as caseentity

 JOIN systemuser ak ON ak.systemuserid = caseentity.owninguser
 JOIN teammembership teammembership ON teammembership.systemuserid = 
 ak.systemuserid
 JOIN team al ON al.teamid = teammembership.teamid 

WHERE cast(caseentity.createdon as 
  date)>=DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE())
    and al.Name='abc'
    GROUP BY al.Name
```

Here I am getting wrong result for the count of closed cases.
case when cast(c1.CreatedOn as date) between cast(DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) as date) and (c1.StateCode) then COUNT(*) end as [created cases], can i mention some thing like this to the column itself? –

Comment: The query start is missing above.

Comment: yes, copy mistake there is a select

Comment: These things happen. But now you should edit your question.

Comment: How do you know how many cases have closed in the last 7 days when you don’t appear to have a closed date in your dataset?

Comment: can i add in the column as condition how can i do that?

Comment: You use CASE with COUNT. Usually is SUM(CASE....THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: case when cast(c1.CreatedOn as date) between  cast(DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) as date) and (c1.StateCode) then COUNT(*)  end as [created cases],     can i mention some thing like this to the column itself?

Comment: You asked this previously. I answered but you never gave any input sample data to test against. Look at my answer here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75680620/how-to-show-how-many-cases-created-which-are-active-and-how-many-resolved-in-the

Comment: sum and count giving the same result.

Comment: in the where condition if i mention createdon and resolved on then if one is false then it won't give result, hence i think i need to do that with those 2 columns itself. any idea how to do that?

Comment: Please don’t add additional information or ask additional questions in comments. You need to update your question so that someone reading the question for the first time can understand what you are asking and can see all the supporting information. Having to wade through a load of comments to work out what is relevant makes it difficult to help you

Comment: SUM (CASE WHEN caseentity.statecode=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ClosedCases]